# ajuda com laço for, com variável aproximando de 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um trabalho com imagens e tenho o código abaixo:

```
var tempoTransicao = 5;
var quantasImagens = $("ul.slider li img").size();
var tamanhoIntervalos = Math.round(100/quantasImagens);
var t = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= quantasImagens; i++) {                              
    tMin = t + tempoTransicao;
    tMax = t + tamanhoIntervalos;    
    t+=tamanhoIntervalos;
    //if(t=~100) i=quantasImagens;
    alert("tMin: "+tMin);
    alert("tMax: "+tMax);
    alert("t: "+t);
}
```

A ideia é um laço `for` que passe em corra de 0 a 100%, preenchendo quadros de  `tamanhoIntervalos %`. Tudo funciona bem, mas preciso arranjar uma forma de quando chegar no último laço, fazer `i=quantasImagens`.

Aí é que está minha dificuldade, pois na última iteração quase nunca a variável `tMax` vai receber valor `100%`.

Também tentei com a variável `i` iterando de 0 a 100%:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                    
    tMin = i + tempoTransicao;
    tMax = i + tamanhoIntervalos;          
    if (i == 0 ) {
        tMin = 0;
    } else if  (i == 100) {
        //tMax = 100;
    }      
    
    //alert("tempoTransicao: "+tempoTransicao);
    //alert("tMin: "+tMin);
    //alert("tMax: "+tMax);
    
    i = tMax==100 ? 100 : tMax-1;
    
}
```

HTML

```
 <ul class="slider">
    <li> 
      <img src="_imgs/_slideShow/1.png" /> 
      <img src="_imgs/_slideShow/2.png" /> 
      <img src="_imgs/_slideShow/3.png" /> 
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Alguém me ajuda a encontrar essa lógica?

Comment: No primeiro `for`, para identificar a última iteração você pode fazer `if (i == quantasImagens) { ... }`

Comment: era isso mesmo, pode me ajudar com essa dúvida também fazendo favor? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249014/criar-uma-anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para identificar a última iteração no laço, basta você verificar o valor da sua variável de controle. No seu caso, a variável de controle é `i` e varia de 0 a `quantasImagens`, então quando ela possuir o mesmo valor de `quantasImagens` será a última iteração do laço:

```
var tempoTransicao = 5;
var quantasImagens = $("ul.slider li img").size();
var tamanhoIntervalos = Math.round(100/quantasImagens);
var t = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= quantasImagens; i++) {                              
    tMin = t + tempoTransicao;
    tMax = t + tamanhoIntervalos;    
    t+=tamanhoIntervalos;
    //if(t=~100) i=quantasImagens;
    alert("tMin: "+tMin);
    alert("tMax: "+tMax);
    alert("t: "+t);

    if (i == quantasImagens) {
        // Faça algo na última iteração...
    }
}
```

Veja um exemplo simples:

```js
for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    
    if (i == 5) {
        console.log("Terminou");
    }
}
```

Comment: era isso mesmo, pode me ajudar com essa dúvida também fazendo favor? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249014/criar-uma-anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-jquery